# Python Selenium Webdriver Chrome windows [4512:11852:0709/110013:ERROR:textfield.h(162)] NOT IMPLEMENTED

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

if I start my Selenium test for Chrome in Windows

1. I have to wait 30 Seconds til Chrome comes up
2. The Url is loaded but nothing happens

In the shell I get the following message
[4512:11852:0709/110013:ERROR:textfield.h(162)] NOT IMPLEMENTED

If I Use Firefox() instead all works fine

Chrome Version: Version 27.0.1453.116 m

Chrome Driver: ChromeDriver server for win32 (v2.0.204324.dyu) supports Chrome v27-29

Comment: Some more details would be nice. What version of Chrome? What version of Chrome Driver? When did this start happening? Has Chrome auto-updated recently? What if you use Firefox instead?

Comment: Thanks for answering I updated the question and I hope you can now help me